# How to pass multiple arguments when calling a function when building a basic calculator?

Tags: python

I want to build a basic calculator that'll ask the user for as many numbers as the user wants and add all of them and print the answer back to the user. This is my code:

```
def add(*args):
    return(f"The answer is {sum(args)}")

user_number = int(input("Enter the first number that you want added: "))
user_number = int(input("Now the second number: "))

user_choice = input("Do you want to add more numbers? ")

while user_choice != "no":
    user_number = int(input("Then please enter the number: "))
    user_choice = input("Continue? ")

print(add(user_number))
```

My function here can take as many parameters as the user needs but I am failing to pass those multiple numbers to the function. When the function is called and printed, only the latest `user_number` gets printed. This is because the `user_number` gets changed every time, so my function is not able to add the numbers that the user has inputted. I need some way of making `user_number` keep every single of its values so that my function can add them.

Comment: Create a list outside of the loop and `append` the numbers to it inside the loop.

Comment: What you describe - "I need some way of making user_number keep every single of its values" - is the definition of a `list` (which is in chapter 3 of the official tutorial - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the results to a list you can sum the numbers in the list.

```
user_numbers = []
user_numbers.append(int(input("Enter the first number that you want added: ")))
```

Then you can sum the numbers in the list just like you do now:
`sum(user_numbers)`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a list to capture all the user input and then once done have the sum returned.

```
numbers = []
while True:
    n = int(input('Enter a number: '))
    numbers.append(n)
    choice = input('do you want to add more numbers?')
    if choice.lower() == 'no':
        break
return sum(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on much easier way for the user:

```
user_numbers = list(map(int, input('Enter numbers: ').split()))

sum_numbers = sum(user_numbers)
print (sum_numbers)
```

-> Enter numbers: 4 5 6 7 43

65